# table row renders outside the table parent

Tags: html

i'm trying to make html email, i used tables and everything went fine but the last row  is rendering outside the parent table while in the code i put that table row inside the parent table .

here's the source code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   </head>

 <body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#abccba" style="padding:40px 0 30px 0;">
                <img src="images/r1.png" alt="Creating Email Magic" width="600" height="280" style="display: block;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
               <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                   <tr>
                       <td style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td style="padding: 20px 0 30px 10px;">
                           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit amet tempora, error provident enim laborum, officia praesentium, fugiat ex consequatur nulla dolor obcaecati odit dolorem autem sapiente blanditiis sed quia?
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                   <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                       <tr>
                         <td width="260" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">
                             <table>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td><img src="images/left.png" alt="leftIMG" width="100%" height="140" style="display:block;"></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni nostrum maxime beatae, facere facilis dolorem maiores sed inventore vero possimus. Ratione consequuntur repellendus dolores aspernatur quam cum reiciendis itaque accusantium.</td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </td>
                         <td width="20" style="font-size:0; line-height: 0;">
                              &nbsp;
                         </td>
                         <td width="266" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">
                             <table>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td><img src="images/right.png" alt="rightIMG" width="100%" height="140" style="display:block;"></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laborum cupiditate officia debitis sed qui quaerat totam animi ipsum eius ex voluptatem harum laboriosam repellendus ut doloremque, saepe quos aliquid!</td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
               </table> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ee5c50" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            col1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            col2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

ps: i'm trying to follow this 
[tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770)

the last table row was working fine at the beginning but now it won't accept any attributes

this is the part of the code that i'm having trouble with

```html
<tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ee5c50" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            col1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            col2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Dumping it in https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea gives 37 errors. This syntax is mostly deprecated. I would try a different tutorial that is compatible with HTML5 standards. To pick one error at random, you can't have a `<table>` as a child element of another `<table>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tables which hold the img tags are inside a parent table, but they are not inside their own row and cell. The last table then renders outside of the parent table. See the code below.

To debug, I used the developer console in a browser, then inspected each element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   </head>

 <body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#abccba" style="padding:40px 0 30px 0;">
                <img src="images/r1.png" alt="Creating Email Magic" width="600" height="280" style="display: block;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
               <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                   <tr>
                       <td style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td style="padding: 20px 0 30px 10px;">
                           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit amet tempora, error provident enim laborum, officia praesentium, fugiat ex consequatur nulla dolor obcaecati odit dolorem autem sapiente blanditiis sed quia?
                       </td>
                   </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>
                   <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                       <tr>
                         <td width="260" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">
                             <table>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td><img src="images/left.png" alt="leftIMG" width="100%" height="140" style="display:block;"></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni nostrum maxime beatae, facere facilis dolorem maiores sed inventore vero possimus. Ratione consequuntur repellendus dolores aspernatur quam cum reiciendis itaque accusantium.</td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </td>
                         <td width="20" style="font-size:0; line-height: 0;">
                              &nbsp;
                         </td>
                         <td width="266" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">
                             <table>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td><img src="images/right.png" alt="rightIMG" width="100%" height="140" style="display:block;"></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laborum cupiditate officia debitis sed qui quaerat totam animi ipsum eius ex voluptatem harum laboriosam repellendus ut doloremque, saepe quos aliquid!</td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
               </table> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ee5c50" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            col1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            col2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your third table was causing trouble.As it was outside of tr.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            var datetime = new Date();
            var res = datetime.toString(); //res is the variable
            function submitForm() {
                $("#loginDetails input[name=dateTime]").val(res);
                console.log($("#loginDetails input[name=dateTime]").val());
                $("#loginDetails").submit();
            }
            function selectItem() {
                var selectedCars = $("#carsDropDown").val();
                console.log($("#carsDropDown").val());
            }

        </script>

        <body>
            <div class="col-xs-8 center login-sub-container clearfix">
                <form id="loginDetails" name="loginDetails" action="http://192.198.9.228/loginOnline" method="post">
                    <div class="login-form-elements">
                        <input type="hidden" value=res name="dateTime"> // here the result i want to pass
                    </div>
                    <select id="carsDropDown" multiple="multiple" onclick="selectItem()">
                        <option name="carCode" selected="selected" value="ALL">All Cars</option>
                        <option value="AUD" name="carCode">Audi</option>
                        <option value="BMW" name="carCode">BMW</option>
                        <option value="FOR" name="carCode">Ford</option>
                        <option value="SAB" name="carCode">Saab</option>
                        <option value="VOL" name="carCode">Volvo</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();">
                    <button type="submit" class="qbutton  default" style="">FIND NOW</button>
                </form>
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                    <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                </head>

                <body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#abccba" style="padding:40px 0 30px 0;">
                                <img src="images/r1.png" alt="Creating Email Magic" width="600" height="280" style="display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>           

                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
                                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 20px 0 30px 10px;">
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit amet tempora, error provident enim laborum, officia praesentium,
                                            fugiat ex consequatur nulla dolor obcaecati odit dolorem autem sapiente blanditiis sed quia?
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="260" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">
                                                                <table>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <img src="images/left.png" alt="leftIMG" width="100%" height="140" style="display:block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni nostrum maxime beatae, facere facilis dolorem
                                                                            maiores sed inventore vero possimus. Ratione consequuntur repellendus dolores aspernatur quam cum reiciendis
                                                                            itaque accusantium.</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td width="20" style="font-size:0; line-height: 0;">
                                                                &nbsp;
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td width="266" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px">
                                                                <table>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <img src="images/right.png" alt="rightIMG" width="100%" height="140" style="display:block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laborum cupiditate officia debitis sed qui quaerat
                                                                            totam animi ipsum eius ex voluptatem harum laboriosam repellendus ut doloremque, saepe quos aliquid!</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ee5c50" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px">
                                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            col1
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            col2
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </body>

                </html>
            </div>
        </body>

    </html>
```